# Comparing user input to some fields in an array of JSON objects

Tags: json, angularjs, for-loop

I have a webserver with JSON data in it. This is what my data looks like

```
[
  {
    iduser: 1,
    username: "joe",
    password: "****"
  },
  {
    iduser: 2,
    username: "gina",
    password: "****"
  }
]
```

In my app I take some user input and wish to compare it to the username and password field. Here is where I check the data

```
.service('LoginService', function ($q, $http) {
  return {
    loginUser: function (name, pw) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        var user_data = $http.get("http://<my ip address>:<port>/login");
        user_data.then(function ($scope, result) {
            $scope.user = result.data;
        })
        for (var x in $scope.user) {
            if (name == x.username && pw == x.password) {
                deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
            } else {
                deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
            }
        }
        promise.success = function (fn) {
            promise.then(fn);
            return promise;
        }
        promise.error = function (fn) {
            promise.then(null, fn);
            return promise;
        }
        return promise;
    }
  }
})
```

I am still learning angularJS and I know this is not a secure way to check the data I just want this loop to work.

My understanding of what I have here is that $scope.user holds my JSON data. Then the data is cycled through with the for loop and the user input name is compared to the field username of each iteration. But this is not the case as I am getting a fail every time.

I'm almost certain its a syntax error, but I don't know JavaScript or AngularJS well enough to find the problem. Any help is really appreciated, Thanks.

**Edit 1**

After what Nujabes said I made some changes since I don't need $scope.

```
//previous code the same
user_data.then(function (result) {
  var user = result.data;
})
for (var x in user) {
  if (name == x.username && pw == x.password) {
//prior code the same
```

I don't think var can hold the data and thats why I'm still getting errors. I think it should be in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax error is that you omit $scope.

You should inject $scope service to this line:

.service('LoginService',function($q,$http,$scope){ ...
});

And this code :

```
user_data.then(function ($scope, result) {
        $scope.user = result.data;
    });
```

Omit the $scope.

->

```
user_data.then(function (result) {
            $scope.user = result.data;
        });
```

like this.

Give it a try.

I hope it work.

(However, why do you want to use $scope service in your 'service'?
 I think, defining local value and returning some method is a better choice.
 and you use the $scope service in your 'controller'.)

Comment: adding $scope to the top causes my login screen to not display. I'm still quite new to all this angularJS stuff. So i can get rid of scope all together and store the data from my http request in an array perhaps?

Comment: Can you show me the message that you faced in your console? You said your login screen doesn't display, then check your console. I want to see those message.

Comment: Can you do this? define var userArr =[] code above and in the callback function userArr = result.data;

Comment: I got it using a w3 schools basic JSON for loop. but couldn't have gotten it without you telling me to drop the $scope. cheers man

Answer (score 0):

$scope.user you are trying to loop through is array right ? 
using (for/in) will store the key in the variable x which is in your case the index of each element (0,1,2,..) , to loop through arrays use (for/of) like this :

```
for (var value of array)
```

this will give you the values ...